# Get content width of an element

Tags: javascript

`offsetWidth` isn't good enough for me right now, as this includes padding and border width. I want to find out the content width of the element. Is there a property for that, or do I have to take the offsetWidth and then subtract the padding and border width from the computed style?

Answer (score 17):

Since this comes up first when googling but doesn't have an appropriate answer yet, here's one:

```
function getContentWidth (element) {
  var styles = getComputedStyle(element)

  return element.clientWidth
    - parseFloat(styles.paddingLeft)
    - parseFloat(styles.paddingRight)
}
```

Basically, we first get the element's width including the padding (`clientWidth`) and then substract the padding left and right. We need to `parseFloat` the paddings because they come as `px`-suffixed strings.

---

I've created a little playground for this on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/loilo/full/xJqEQb), check it out!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you want to use `getComputedStyle` on the element. You can see an example of `getComputedStyle` vs. `offsetWidth` here: http://jsbin.com/avedut/2/edit

Or:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('your-element')).width;
```

Comment: Oh and another thing, I specifically gave that option in my question. I'm looking for another one.

Comment: That would have been an important bit to include from the start. ;-) And in that case, yes: I think you need to do some subtraction. I've added a `getWidth` to the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/avedut/6/edit (and the way it was phrased there at the end tripped me up a little, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest either `scrollWidth` or the `clientWidth` depending on whether you want to account for the scrollbar.

Check out [Determining the dimensions of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements) or the [specification itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/).

Comment: Sorry, both of these seem to be giving the same as the `offsetWidth`.

Comment: Those include padding.

Comment: This is the only answer that handles content that exceeds the viewport's size. +1

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue where my parent element isn't the window or document... I am loading an image by Javascript and want it to center after loading.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('yourparentid');
var image = document.getElementById('yourimageid');
image.addEventListener('load'),function() {
    parent.scrollBy((image.width-parent.clientWidth)/2,(image.height-parent.clientHeight)/2);
}
```

Whenever you set the src then it will scroll to the center of the image. This for me is in the context of zooming into a high res version of the image.