# get div content width without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following element

```
<div id='mydiv' style='width: 0px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>
    Lots of content
</div>
```

I am using jQuery to slide open the content like this

```
$("#mydiv").animate({width:this[0].scrollWidth},{duration:200});
```

But I'm trying to minimise my reliance on jQuery and I want to do this with css transitions instead, so the css would be:

```
#mydiv { transition: width 200ms ease-in-out; }
```

And the javascript would be:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.width = ???
```

How do I find the element content's width without jQuery?

Comment: Similar topic is discussed here. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438064/get-content-width-of-an-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this

```
if(var el = document.getElementById("mydiv"))
  el.style.width = el.scrollWidth + "px";
```

what you were looking for?

Comment: yes, this works. sorry, i forgot to add the +"px" to the value

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width of the element (i.e. content + padding + border) by using:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth
```

Maybe have a look at “[Determining the dimensions of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)” at the Mozilla Developer Networks.

Answer (score 0):

to set its width, write

```
var x = 5; 
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.width = x + "px";
```

to get its width, write

```
var x = document.getElementById("mydiv").style.width;
```

note the automatic conversion to string with `x + "px"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's even simpler and more straightforward one-line code:

```
var width = document.getElementById('mydiv').offsetWidth;
```